# Circular dependency error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :fteams
end

class TeamPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :players, through: :team_players
end
```

And i get the error: RuntimeError in Teamplayers#index: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Player.

I would like to know what it means and how to fix it. I have already downgraded my rails from 4.0.2 to 4.0.0 and I still have the same problem, and it seems like a simple fix, but it's frustrating, searching the internet and coming up with nothing

Comment: Can you post all of the code for your player model? Or is that it?

Comment: i updated my player model, so yeah that's it

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a many to many relationship right? As in, a player can be part of lots of teams, and teams can have lots of players? Try something like this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :teams, through: :team_players
end

class TeamPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :players, through: :team_players
end
```

Comment: ok now that's fixed i got this error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: teamplayers.live_player_id: SELECT "teamplayers".* FROM "teamplayers" INNER JOIN "players" ON "players"."id" = "teamplayers"."player_id", when trying to run this line: `<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:player), "teamid", "playerid") %>` why is that. I know that the column it is looking for does not exists but why is it looking for teamplayers.player_id

Comment: It's because `belongs_to :player` requires a `player_id` column in the `TeamPlayer` table. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association for an example of a many-to-many relationship

Comment: So by creating the migration file that would take care of it? would I have to fully define my tables in the file, or just the fields that need to be associated?

Comment: Depends what your database schema is like now - if you already created the tables, you don't have to do it again. If you haven't, then you'll obviously have to create them in a migration

Comment: i have created the tables but there is no teamplayers.player_id would i just have to add that column or redo the tables, which i could do and don't mind in the migration file

Comment: You'd create a new migration, which adds the column player_id to the team players table